# Load contents of image from camera to a file

Tags: cordova, angularjs, parse-platform, ripple

I am taking a picture (or selecting from library) using phonegap API using the following drictive:

```
MyApp.directive('Camera', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            elm.bind('click', function() {
                navigator.camera.getPicture(function (imageURI)
                {
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                        ctrl.$setViewValue(imageURI);
                    });
                }, function (err) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('error', false);
                },
                //Options => http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera
                { quality: 50,
                  destinationType:Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI                      
                })
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Which return me a URI that looks like, using ripple emulator on chrome, which I cann see pasting this URI.

```
blob:http%3A//localhost%3A8080/8e18de30-d049-4ce2-ae88-8500b444581e
```

My issue is loading this URI

```
$scope.updateUserProfile = function (user) {

       var myPicfile = $http.get(user.myPicture);

       dataService.uploadPicture . . . some code to update the picture to Parse

    }
```

*Note: [I cannot use phonegap filetransfer together with parse.com  :](https://parse.com/questions/file-upload-returns-201-but-doesnt-seem-to-be-valid)

When I do that I get:

[image]

I am making my request like:

uploadPicture: function uploadPicture(user,callback)
            {
                var serverUrl = 'https://api.parse.com/1/files/' + user.Nick ;

```
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: serverUrl,
                data: user.myPicture,
                headers: {'X-Parse-Application-Id': PARSE_APP_ID,
                    'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': PARSE_REST_API_KEY,
                    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
                }
            })
```

Any idea on how to get the content of the image to a file that then I can happily upload to Parse.com?

Thanks!

Comment: Check this [Storing Captured Photo on SD Card](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928202/save-image-in-local-storage-phonegap/16648829#16648829)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally work it around, since my ultimate goal was to use it with phonegap, [with the info in this post](https://www.raymondcamden.com/2013/07/10/Quick-note-for-Parse-and-JavaScript-Users). . Big thanks to Raymond Camden!

```
function gotPic(data) {

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(data, function(entry) {

var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(evt.target.result);
    var output = new Array( byteArray.length );
    var i = 0;
    var n = output.length;
    while( i < n ) {
        output[i] = byteArray[i];
        i++;
    }                
    var parseFile = new Parse.File("mypic.jpg", output);

    parseFile.save().then(function(ob) {
            navigator.notification.alert("Got it!", null);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(ob));
        }, function(error) {
            console.log("Error");
            console.log(error);
        });

}

reader.onerror = function(evt) {
      console.log('read error');
      console.log(JSON.stringify(evt));
  }

entry.file(function(s) {
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(s);
}, function(e) {
    console.log('ee');
});

});
}
```