# How to store the pics taken from an Phonegap/Android application

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, camera, cordova

I was trying to execute the CAMERA program available on Phonegap docs.

I am new to PhoneGap.

While Executing that program I found out that,pics that are taken from the app,does not get stored anywhere.

**2 queries**

**query 1)** That is i take pictures,...those are there....when i come and open the app for the 2nd time..no Pics(here I open the application **twice**)

**query 2)** Suppose, I select 1 photo from the gallery,now i want the other photo too...when i select the second the 1st one vanishes....(here I open the application **once**)

**Where should I store** the photos clicked from the app and **HOW should I store** --i mean the procedure to do it/method to be followed.

suggestions and solutions please!!

Comment: You will have to store the photo path in local database. Check my answer to this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928202/save-image-in-local-storage-phonegap/16648829#16648829)

Answer (score 1):

To save the picture, someone has written a plugin. You can find it here : [base64ToPNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388018/phonegap-plugin-to-convert-base64-string-to-a-png-image-in-android/11388019#11388019)

And you can get the base64 just like in phonegap docs [camera.getPicture](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#camera.getPicture)

Comment: thank you, for this answer.but, could please explain what does this code stands for `var myBase64 = "data:img/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="//a red dot` and this `window.plugins.base64ToPNG.saveImage(myBase64, {filename:"dot.png", overwrite: true},`

Comment: **Could you please explain the working process of the suggested answer?** As I am new to the PhoneGap domain.