# Phonegap and Jquery to get a Photo stored on the device and convert it to a base64 string, path is from the sqlite database

Tags: jquery, cordova

I am having some problems converting the image into a base64 string to transmit over the xml. I stored the Image location(full path) into the database when I took the photo and I'm trying to upload it now. I am trying to Read the file that I have in the(results.rows.item(i).PictureFile) and then convert that to base64. Below is the part of the code im using to do this. Anything anyone can do to help would be great.

```
   function submitPhoto(PhotoId)
{
    g_submitXML = '';
    var err = '';
    var errorsArr = $.makeArray(err);
    window.g_submitXML = '';
    window.g_submitXML = window.g_submitXML + '';
    window.g_submitXML = window.g_submitXML + '';
    window.g_submitXML = window.g_submitXML + '';
    console.log("successfully started the xml with: " + window.g_submitXML);

    var db = window.openDatabase("MobileData", "3.0", "MobilePhoneData", 1000000);
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM MobilePhotos WHERE PhotoId = ' + PhotoId + '', 
          [], 
            function(tx, results) {
                console.log("HIT THE RESULTS PHOTO FUNCTION");
                var len = results.rows.length;
                console.log("Photo table: " + len + " rows found.");
                 for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
                    {
                     window.g_submitXML = window.g_submitXML + '<EMBEDDED_FILE _Type="JPEG" _Name="Image_' + i + '"';
                     window.g_submitXML = window.g_submitXML + '_Extension=.jpg _EncodingType="Base64" _ImageOrientation="' + results.rows.item(i).PictureLocationDesc + '">';
                     window.g_submitXML = window.g_submitXML + '<DOCUMENT>';
                     var reader = new FileReader();
                 console.log(results.rows.item(i).PictureFile);
//I am having problems with the line below
                     window.g_submitXML = window.g_submitXML + reader.readAsDataURL(fileSystem.root.getFile(results.rows.item(i).PictureFile));
//I am having problems with the line above ^
                     window.g_submitXML = window.g_submitXML + '</DOCUMENT>';
                     window.g_submitXML = window.g_submitXML + '</EMBEDDED_FILE>';
                    }
        }, 
        console.log("ERROR"));
});


}
```

Ive commented above and below the line I'm having issues with.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you storing the image? [Phonegap's camera API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#camera.getPicture) gives the base64 image. Why don't you directly use that to upload?

Comment: Napster, For some reason when I store it as a base 64 image the application slows down a lot. The method for taking a photo calls this: navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, function(ex) {alert("Camera Error!");}, { quality : 100, destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
 }); If you Know of a way to optimize that so it does not cause the application to eventually crash I would prefer to store the base 64 image inside of the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it the following way.

Check answer to **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928202/save-image-in-local-storage-phonegap/16648829#16648829)**

Then I used following code to upload image using web service.

```
//function to upload image
function uploadImage(ImagePath)
{
    try
    {
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey = "file";
        options.fileName = ImagePath;
        options.mimeType = "image/jpg";

        var params = new Object();    
        //You can set multiple params
        options.params = params;
        options.chunkedMode = false;
        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        var url = "My_WebService_URL";
        ft.upload(ImagePath, url, win, fail, options, false);
    } 
    catch (e) 
    {
        console.error("Error :"+e.message);
    }
}
//Success callback
function win(response) 
{
    alert("Image uploaded successfully!!");
}
//Failure callback
function fail(error) 
{
    alert("There was an error uploading image");
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Unfortunately I have to send it in an xml :-/ The XML has a lot of other information along with the photos (between 4 and 12).

Comment: Thanks though, I think I was having a memory issue, I ended up just bumping the quality down to 50 and saved it as base 64 when i took the photo.