# original image path from Phonegap File transfer API

Tags: cordova, file-transfer

I was trying phonegap File transfer API to upload files to remote server and it is working fine. But i have issue in getting original file path. The 'imageURI' returns temporary path, so I tried "window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI" to get the original path. But the following code not return any path. Please help me to know where I am wrong.

```
<script>

  function getphoto() {

     navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, function(message) {alert('get picture failed');
}, { quality:10, destinationType:navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, sourceType:navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY }); 

}


    function uploadPhoto(imageURI)
            {

                   window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imageURI, gotFileEntry, function(error){onfail(console.log("Error get fullPath"))});
            }

function gotFileEntry(imageURI) { 
             alert("imageURI: "+imageURI);
 //not getting imageURI
} 

</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the significance behind getting original filepath?

Comment: From the file name I need to check whether the image has already uploaded or not..

Comment: and the above code shows only jpg images in the phone while uploading.IS there any way I can upload all image type?

Comment: that is not possible...Cordova currently not supporting multiple image format together

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet can help you.. :-) use ***imageData.nativeURL*** for orginal file path

```
            navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
        quality : 75, 
        destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, 
        sourceType : navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM , 
        mediaType : navigator.camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA //all mediaFiles
    });

    function onSuccess(imageData) {
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imageData, gotFileEntry, 
            function(error){
                alert("Error get fullPath");
            }
        );
        function gotFileEntry(imageURI) { 
         // alert("imageURI: "+JSON.stringify(imageURI));
         alert("imageURI: "+imageURI.nativeURL);
        }
    }

    function onFail(message) {
        alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be possible, simply changing the extension.

Check following links

- To take a photo and store it in local database try [Store Photo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928202/save-image-in-local-storage-phonegap/16648829#16648829)
- To upload it to the server using web service try [Upload to
  Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17326901/phonegap-and-jquery-to-get-a-photo-stored-on-the-device-and-convert-it-to-a-base/17343491#17343491)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. But in that solution the image name is created with current date time. But my requirement is to get the original image name. Is that possible? And regarding the different image type, is it possible that I can specify jpg and png extension together?

Comment: 1. It seems to me that captured photo using camera cannot give you original file name. So you have to store image on SD card or `localstorage`. And then check if the image is uploaded or not.
2. For png images phonegap camera api has `EncodingType` attribute. Refer [Camera API Documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html)

Comment: Check [this](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html#cameraOptions) and try to implement the examples provided by phonegap.

Comment: I had already tried that. function getImage() {
           navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, function(message) {
 alert('get picture failed');
       }, {
 quality: 50,
 destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
 sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
                  encodingType:  Camera.EncodingType = { JPEG : 0, PNG : 1}
            }
        );
} but it is showing error while uploading image.Not sure is it bacuse Camera.EncodingType is not supported in Android(I tested in android phone)

Comment: That is not possible...Cordova currently not supporting multiple image format together... thanks for the reply Amol..