# how to save phonegap camera API into gallery too not just local storage

Tags: android, cordova, camera, storage

I posted a post earlier asking how to save the image into local storage and I figured I was being stupid that for the whole time I did save the image captured into local storage but each time I was checking gallery instead of local file so my previous post was pretty lame
[how to use phonegap-2.9.0 camera and store in android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20066036/how-to-use-phonegap-2-9-0-camera-and-store-in-android-device)

again this is my code and I expect this is where I need to do some editing but I don't know how

```
// A button will call this function
function capturePhoto() {
  // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail,{ quality: 50,
    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI, saveToPhotoAlbum: true });
}
```

also, there's something weird I was searching and asking around and someone gave me the same code so I tried AGAIN...AND after taking a picture I found the image in gallery.  I thought it finally worked and I took another picture and this time it only saved into local and not showing in gallery. Then I tried at least 10 times without doing any editing but just won't show in gallery and lots people were saying adding saveToPhotoAlbum: true is what they do and it works.

The only way I found that it'll work is if I restart my phone then I will see all the pictures in my gallery.

Can someone give me a hand please?  Thanks in advance