# Save video to library after capturing video using phonegap 'captureVideo'

Tags: android, ios, video, cordova

I was able to save the captured photo to the library or photo album by using this codes:

```
navigator.device.capture.captureImage(captureSuccess, captureError, 
{limit:25,destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,saveToPhotoAlbum:true});
```

However, I also want to save the captured video as well, but I have tried and had no success. I am using this below code:

```
navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit:1, duration:60,destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,saveToPhotoAlbum:true });
```

I am using Phonegap 3.0.0 and currently focusing on iOS app and Android apl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got this working now for iOS and Cordova 2.9. (Test on iOS7).

All I have to do is to:

- Remove comment the from this method (processVideo)

  -(CDVPluginResult*)processVideo:(NSString*)moviePath forCallbackId:(NSString*)callbackId
  {
      // save the movie to photo album (only avail as of iOS 3.1)

  ```
  /* don't need, it should automatically get saved*/
   NSLog(@"can save %@: %d ?", moviePath, UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(moviePath));
  if (&UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum != NULL && UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(moviePath) == YES) {
      NSLog(@"try to save movie");
      UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(moviePath, nil, nil, nil);
      NSLog(@"finished saving movie");
  }
  // create MediaFile object
  NSDictionary* fileDict = [self getMediaDictionaryFromPath:moviePath ofType:nil];
  NSArray* fileArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:fileDict];

  return [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsArray:fileArray];
  ```

  }

**Note:**
They tell that don't need it, it should automatically get saved. But for my case, it did not get saved.

- Rebuild the Cordova library
- After rebuild, if you have some issues with linker, do remove arm64, arm7s architecture from Valid Architecture from Build Setting of your project.
- And then you got your video saved.

I got hint from : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/hN09oEYF0lk

Comment: where is the location of that method

Comment: I think this one is in the file  CDVCapture.m of Cordova lib project that is in your project's xcode

Comment: I am in developing windows

Comment: I did exactly what you wrote sean and no luck. Uncommenting the .m file code is straightforward. What was your final JS method call? Still: navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit:1, duration:60,destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,saveToPhotoAlbum:true });   ?

Comment: @shammon Oh that time I was developing for iOS version for Android version I have not tested that yet.

Comment: @Colton45 What phonegap version you are using? It is a while ago that I was developing with that

Answer (score 0):

Change this to

```
navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit:1, duration:60,destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,saveToPhotoAlbum:true });
```

to

```
navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit: 1,duration:60});
```

Secondly limit property is not supported in IOS. For more details you can check the phonegap [link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html#CaptureVideoOptions)

Comment: Thanks! Let me try to change and test it.

Comment: Hi Divesh Salian.  I have changed to navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, {}); // removing all options, but it still did not save to camera roll.

Comment: is your camera getting opened ? If yes do u get any error after completing the recording?

Comment: Everything worked fine. The camera opened, I captured and transferred to server successfully. The only problem is it does not save to camera roll. I tested on iOS >=6.

Comment: Get the video path... make use of some file explorer and check whether that file exist... [Check](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20066036/how-to-use-phonegap-2-9-0-camera-and-store-in-android-device/20066497#20066497) the last comment for my answer might be you getting the same problem

Comment: I try to find but did not see (maybe in Android is working, but in iOS I could not find the captured video). But I will try to debug the video path to know where is it.