# Display locally saved picture with Cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova, local-storage

I'm developing an iOS & Android mobile app with Cordova, and i'm facing a problem with saving and displaying a picture taken from camera or camera roll, and saved locally. 

I've already seen other conversations on the subject : 
[Save image in local storage phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928202/save-image-in-local-storage-phonegap) 
[Capturing and storing a picture taken with the Camera into a local database / PhoneGap / Cordova / iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335563/capturing-and-storing-a-picture-taken-with-the-camera-into-a-local-database-ph)

I'm using the scripts described in these conversations which are good, but finally can't achieve to display the saved pictures.

I know pictures have been successfully saved in a persistent folder on my iPhone, i can see them, using iExplorer software, in my app subfolders, for example : Documents/MyApp/cdv_photo_002.jpg 

And i save in my localStorage the fullPath of the local picture and obtain something like : file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4E70258E-8060-48A6/Documents/MyApp/cdv_photo_002.jpg 

When i try to put this path in an img src, nothing is displayed as if the picture did not exist or not having this path... 
How can i display my local pictures ?

Comment: Does your app got READING and writing permissions?

Comment: Do you see an error in console?

Comment: Yes, i have r/w permissions and i have no error in console

Comment: Did u get any solution?

Comment: yes, the problem was about fetching the local system path, so i had to put the path in a local storage item using `window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSys) {localStorage.setItem('_localsys', fileSys.root.toURL());});`

Comment: I get the fileSys roo url as "file:///Users/name/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A8243D1F-24C4-437D-BAC5-76EBF99B68FB/data/Containers/Data/Application/C9B9F008-F56F-4C6D-B692-4DF73E5EE8B8/Documents/". How to get the image url

Comment: Colud u pls suggest solution for me? Am getting entry.nativeURL as "file:///Users/mohanvel.v/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A8243D1F-24C4-437D-BAC5-76EBF99B68FB/data/Containers/Data/Application/ED53ACD1-FF4F-416E-8499-D4FDB9894A31/Documents/xxx/cdv_photo_001.jpg", how to display this image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Matthieu Marcé pointed out, the answer of this question should be :

> the problem was about fetching the local system path, so i had to put
>   the path in a local storage item using

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
function(fileSys) {
      localStorage.setItem('_localsys',fileSys.root.toURL());
   }
);
```