# save image file in local storage and retrieve image from file path html cordova apps

Tags: ios, html, cordova, local-storage, apache-cordova

Its quite strange that from all the references i try to save and retrieve images from local storage but it does not display image after app is relaunched.

Tried all possible suggestions in the below links.

[save-image-in-local-storage-phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928202/save-image-in-local-storage-phonegap)

[Save image in local database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335563/capturing-and-storing-a-picture-taken-with-the-camera-into-a-local-database-ph)

[capture-and-store-images](https://devdactic.com/how-to-capture-and-store-images-with-ionic/)

```
 function successMove(entry) {

        var sr = entry.nativeURL;
    }
```

After success i tried to save entry.nativeURL,entry.toURL(),entry.fullPath. But all fails. Cant trace where am wrong.

Note: Tested only in IOS simulator, Development using visual studio 2015

Comment: what are the plugins did you use for saving image?

Comment: cordova-plugin-camera,cordova-plugin-media,cordova-plugin-device,cordova-plugin-file,cordova-plugin-file-transfer,https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-imagePicker.git

Comment: hi , im currently doing the same thing , how did u save the image file path into sql and reterive it everytime you log to the app

Comment: Just add the nativeURL in a sqlite and then u can bind it to the image as its source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this solved when i deploy my app in a real device like a ipad. Only on simulator i get this error.